# Toggle element visibility based on checkbox state

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm not sure how to accomplish this. What I want to do is to hide a div based on a checkbox value. This is my code for the toggle, `.always` is the checkbox and `#dates` is a div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.always').click(function() {
    $('#dates').toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Off-topic: when using document.ready I think it's better to use the alias/shortcut `jQuery(function($){});`

Comment: thanks for the tip. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) takes a boolean as well, like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('.always').change(function () {                
     $('#dates').toggle(!this.checked);
  }).change(); //ensure visible state matches initially
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/VUeB7/). I assume in the above you want the `#dates` hidden if `.always` is checked, that's what it'll do.

Comment: This don't work for me for some reason. I tried to have the checkbox checked default and it wont respond to it, its still visible.

Comment: Not that I can se. My firebug wont let me debug the JS for some odd reason.

Comment: @Dejan.S - try restarting firefox completely...firebug 1.6 has some issues, several questions around that this morning.

Comment: No luck, its still the same. You got any chance to try this code? checkbox and a div. would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: thanks Nick. Nice site did not know about it. The firebug jump started after a few restarts

Answer (score 8):

```
$('.always').change(function() {
 $('#dates').toggle(!this.checked);
});
```

Comment: change() is much better for this as it even works when the checkbox is changed by some other means.

Comment: By using `.toggle()` you're assuming the visible state matches and was changed no other way, better to pass a boolean to *ensure* it matches :)

Comment: Thanks Nick, I forgot that .toggle accepts a showOrHide value. I'll add that.