# jQuery Show-Hide DIV based on Checkbox Value

Tags: jquery, checkbox, show-hide

Using AJAX I populate a DIV with a bunch of checkboxes (each with it's own unique ID). The IDs are "projectID1", "projectID2", "projectID3" and so on... I have given all checkboxes a class of "pChk".

My end goal is to show the DIV containing the Submit Button if ANY of the checkboxes are checked. The only time the DIV containing the Submit Button show be hidden is if all checkboxes are unchecked.

However the code I have come up with below shows/hides the Submit Button DIV for each checkbox instance. In other words, if I have three checkboxes CHECKED and I UNCHECK one of them, the Submit Button DIV get hidden.

Your expert advice is more than welcome!

```
function checkUncheck() { 
    $('.pChk').click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#ProjectListButton").show();
        } else {
            $("#ProjectListButton").hide();
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Remember that if you *show* the submit button with JS, you should also *hide* the button with JS, so people without JavaScript enabled can *still* use the form. People with screen readers, as an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle div based on checkbox value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337378/toggle-div-based-on-checkbox-value)

Answer (score 60):

While this is old if someone comes across this again (via search). The correct answer with jQuery 1.7 onwards is now:

```
$('.pChk').click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#ProjectListButton").show();
    } else {
        $("#ProjectListButton").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I really do not know why this is so upvoted.. it is wrong. You are only checking the current item while the OP is specifically asking that hiding should only occur if ***ALL*** `.pChk` elements are unchecked.. You have just re-written the code of the question (*which is better because of the direct usage of `this.checked` instead of your using of jquery even for that..*)

Answer (score 17):

I use jQuery prop

```
$('#yourCheckbox').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $('#showDiv').show();
  } else {
    $('#hideDiv').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

That is because you are only checking the current checkbox.

Change it to

```
function checkUncheck() { 
    $('.pChk').click(function() {
        if ( $('.pChk:checked').length > 0) {
            $("#ProjectListButton").show();
        } else {
            $("#ProjectListButton").hide();
        }
    }); 
}
```

to check if any of the checkboxes is checked (*lots of checks in this line..*).

reference: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm!Some people just get it while others like me struggle!

Comment: If we remove ".length > 0" it will not work if there are 2 or more checkbox and 2 or more content to show and hide. But if add ".length > 0" it works like charm.

Can you please explain this logic (will be simple but I am not able to understand).

Comment: @veer that is because `$('.pChk:checked')` always returns a jquery object regardless of having found a matching item or not. And objects evaluate as true in `if` checks.

Comment: Thanks Gaby, yes it returns as object.

Comment: This is the best answer. No need for the function by the way, extra headache for nothing.

Answer (score 6):

ebdiv is set `style="display:none;"`

it is works show & hide

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#eb").click(function(){
        $("#ebdiv").toggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/), provided by jQuery.  Something like this:

```
$('.pChk').click(function() {
    if( $('.pChk:checked').length > 0 ) {
        $("#ProjectListButton").show();
    } else {
        $("#ProjectListButton").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A tip to all people that use flat-red, flat-green plugin, because of this plugin the answers above wont work!

In that case, use onchange="do_your_stuff();" on the label, for example:
 Your checkbox here

The reason why it doesn't work is that this Jquery creates a lot of objects around the real checkbox, so you can't see if it's changed or not.

But if someone click straight on checkbox, won't work :'(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.yourchkboxes').change(function(){
    $('.yourbutton').toggle($('.yourchkboxes:checked').length > 0);
});
```

So it will check for at least one checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

`Display

$('#cbxShowHide').click(function(){
this.checked?$('#block').show(1000):$('#block').hide(1000); //time for show
});`