# On mousenter (hover), show and hide (toggle) a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are multiple divs with a common class. I want use its class to hide / show each div when hovered. I'd prefer using mouseenter / mouseleave. But the issue is that `$target = this.id;` doesn't seem to work.

How do I show/hide a DIV using a class?

```
$(".zz")
            .on( 'mouseenter', function() {
                $target = this.id;
                if( $target.is(':visible') ) return;
                    $target.hide();
            })
            .on( 'mouseleave', function() {
                    $target = this.id
                    if( !$target.is(':visible') ) return;
                        $target.show();
            });
```

EDIT:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3syhn67/10/)

Comment: Firstly, `this.id` is a string, so you can't call jQuery methods on it. You should use `$(this)` to refer the element which raised the event. Finally, if the element is hidden, how can could it be hovered to show it again?

Comment: And unless you've declared `$target` somewhere you haven't shown, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: thanks. sorry about the typo. I've fixed it now.

Comment: I don't understand... What's the reason to down vote?

Comment: I also don't understand. You are trying and having problems with your code and logic. I guess we are meant to help you!

Comment: on mouse over what do you want to show/hide... it it the image

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Show-Hide DIV based on Checkbox Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444292/jquery-show-hide-div-based-on-checkbox-value)

Comment: @ArunPJohny: thanks. Referring to my fiddle example : I want to show `im1` when hovering on `aa`. Then hide on exit. Show `im2` when hovering on `bb`. Then hide on exit.

Comment: @Fergoso: see my new demo link in my answer.

Comment: @Fergoso: your title was a little misleading so I changed it. You were really asking how to show/hide a **child** element, not the parent element you were hovering. That may be why people thought it wasn't a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of chaining multiple `on()` methods together, a better way is to combine all events into one method:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('div[id^="im"]').hide();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find('div[id^="im"]').show();
    },
    click: function() {
        // do something else
    }
}, ".zz");
```

Hope this helps.

[Please see this demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/n3syhn67/14/)

Comment: thanks. But it doesn't work on nested DIVs? E.g: `<div id="aa" class="zz">
    <div id="a1"> <div id = "im1">` I want to hide `im1` when hovering on `aa`. Then hide `im2` when hovering on `bb`. See https://jsfiddle.net/n3syhn67/10/

Comment: @Fergoso: please see updated answer. I have included new demo.

Comment: looks good. But my question was how to hide by div. hOW DO i HIDE THE NESTED DIV INSTEAD OF `$(this).find('img').hide();`

Comment: @Fergoso: please see updated code and demo again. I used `find()` to select any child `div` with an ID beggining with `im`.

Comment: Please up-vote so there are no down-votes to my question. I don't think my question deserves down-votes. thanks.

Comment: @Fergoso: I have upvoted because it does seem unfair. I think people read "how to hide a div" and thought it was an easy task and that you hadn't done research. At least you made an effort by trying it yourself and provided a demo for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery(this) or $(this) to use the element your are entering/leaving and want to add/remove the hide class from.

```
$(".zz")
   .on( 'mouseenter', function() {
      if( $(this).is(':visible') ) return;
      $(this).show();
   })
   .on( 'mouseleave', function() {
      if( !$(this).is(':visible') ) return;
      $(this).hide();
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n3syhn67/2/

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
target = $(this);
```

`this` will refer to the HTMLDiv you want. You have to transform it into a jQuery object in order to use `.is(':visible')` or `.hide()` which are jQuery functions.

```
       .on( 'mouseenter', function() {
            $target = $(this).find("img");
            if( $target.is(':visible') ) return;
                $target.show();
        })
        .on( 'mouseleave', function() {
                $target = $(this).find("img");
                if( !$target.is(':visible') ) return;
                    $target.hide();
        });
```

I have changed the target to `img` element because if you hide the entire dive you can never bring it back on `mouseenter` again.

EDIT:

As an alternative solution you may use opacity instead of hide.

```
    .on( 'mouseenter', function() {
            $target = $(this);
            $target.css({opacity:1});
     })
    .on( 'mouseleave', function() {
            $target = $(this);
            $target.css({opacity:0});
     })
```

Example [Hiding only the image](https://jsfiddle.net/n3syhn67/7/)
Example [Hiding the div with opacity](https://jsfiddle.net/n3syhn67/9/)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this still doesn't work due to the problems with the hide/show logic.

Comment: Got it... I guess now it's what OP wants!

Comment: WHat if I need to hide a div instead? see https://jsfiddle.net/n3syhn67/8/  how do I hide the DIV which has the image?

Comment: Just remove the `.find("img")` expression. But then your code will not make sense. How could you `mouseenter` a hiden div... unless you use opacity

Comment: `$(this)` hides everything. I want to hide only the div with the image. So the background rectangle should be visible at all times.

Answer (score -1):

Updated your code. Hope that helps :)

```
$(".zz")
        .on( 'mouseenter', function(event) {
            $target = $(event.target);
            //$target = this.id;
            if( $target.is(':visible') ) return;
                $target.show();
        })
        .on( 'mouseleave', function(event) {
                $target = $(event.target);
                //$target = this.id
                if( !$target.is(':visible') ) return;
                    $target.hide();
        });
```