# Toggle div visibility based on multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple checkboxes. Checking any of them will make a div visible. Leaving them unchecked will hide the div. It almost works, thanks to Nick (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337378/toggle-div-based-on-checkbox-value) except that I want multiple checkboxes to toggle the div.

HTML:

```
<div id="somediv">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="a" name="a">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="b" name="b">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="c" name="c">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="d" name="d">
</div>

<div id="tog">tog content</div>
```

jQuery:

```
        var tog = $("#tog").hide();
        $('#somediv .form-checkbox').change(function() {              
          if ($(tog).css('display') == 'none') {
            tog.show();
          }       
        });
```

Another one:

```
        var tog = $("#tog").hide();
        $('#somediv .form-checkbox').change(function () {                
            $(tog).toggle(this.checked);
        }).change();
```

What am I missing? 
The issue is when unchecking one of them (not all) hides the div. 
The requirement is only if none is checked, then hide. And hidden by default.
If any is checked, so keep it visible, no toggles.

Any hint would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try -

```
var tog = $("#tog").hide();
 $('#somediv .form-checkbox').change(function () {                
   $(tog).toggle($('.form-checkbox:checked').length > 0);
 }).change();
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/VA4NP/

This is very similar to your second code sample. It uses `$('.form-checkbox:checked').length > 0` as the argument passed to the toggle function, which should return true if any of the checkboxes are checked.

Comment: +1. Using the :checked selector and then checking the length is a very elegant solution. Looping through each of the check boxes and testing their `checked` property is another approach, but it requires more code than this.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
var tog = $("#tog").hide();
$('#somediv').change(function(){
    if($('#somediv').find('input:checked').length === 0)
    {
        tog.hide();
    }
    else
    {
        tog.show();
    }
});
```

Two things to note here. First, you may be able to use `$(this).find` instead of rerunning the selector. I'm not 100% sure what `this` points to in this case (div or checkbox). Secondly, if you have a container filled with inputs that you want to subscribe to events for, its much more efficient to attach the listener to the parent object. The change event from the checkbox will bubble up to the div.

Comment: This works too, except that var tog = $("#tog").hide(); should be placed outside the event. Thanks a lot. I learned a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are right you are close.  What your change event is doing is only taking into account the checked status of the checkbox that was checked or unchecked.  So in the change event, you just need to see if any of the checkboxes are checked.

Maybe something like this:

```
var tog = $("#tog").hide();
$('#somediv .form-checkbox').change(function () {  
    if($('#somediv .form-checkbox').is(':checked').length > 0)
    {
        $(tog).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(tog).hide();
    }
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like:

```
    var tog = $("#tog").hide();
    $('#somediv .form-checkbox').change(function() {
      if ($('#somediv .form-checkbox').is(':checked').length > 0) {
        tog.show();
      } else {
        tog.hide();
      }
    });
```

Comment: nvm. @ipr101 got a better solution.